# When does CPython return unused RSS memory to the OS?

Tags: python, memory, cpython

I am trying to determine the conditions that causes CPython to release unused RSS memory back to the underlying OS?

From the [pypy official docs](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/gc_info.html#gc-get-stats) it says:

> Indeed, returning memory to the OS is a hard and not solved problem.
> In PyPy, it occurs only if an arena is entirely free—a contiguous
> block of 64 pages of 4 or 8 KB each.

What are the conditions for CPython to release unused RSS memory back to the underlying OS?

NOTE:
I know I can use [tracemalloc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) to profile memory usage, my question is more related to how/why RSS memory is released back to the underlying OS for CPython?

Comment: @smcrowley That document is about garbage collection. It's not about returning memory to the OS.

Answer (score 2):

When memory is given back to OS, depends on which memory manager the Python interpreter uses. Usually it is not directly the memory-manager provided by the C runtime, but [`pymalloc-allocator`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html#the-pymalloc-allocator) whose details are probably best described in the [code itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9485a0dbddcee014821b41c960133632bb68b33c/Objects/obmalloc.c).

[For memory sizes > 512bytes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9485a0dbddcee014821b41c960133632bb68b33c/Objects/obmalloc.c#L905), `pymalloc` will delegate the memory request to the underlying C-memory manager. So if you allocate a big `array.array`, the C-memory manager decides when the memory goes back to OS, once the `array.array`-object is destroyed.

However, when you have a lot of objects smaller than 512 bytes, the `pymalloc` is responsible for them. Pre-allocated memory of the pymalloc-allocators consist of so called *arenas*, which are [1MB in size](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9485a0dbddcee014821b41c960133632bb68b33c/Objects/obmalloc.c#L958-L964) (for 64bit systems [`USE_LARGE_ARENAS` is defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9485a0dbddcee014821b41c960133632bb68b33c/Objects/obmalloc.c#L936-L943), for 32bit arena size is 256KB). At the beginning an arena allocates 1MB of virtual memory, which will be committed by the OS as the really used memory grows.

Each arena consist of so called pools: every pool can hold objects of special sizes. When we look in the code, we see, that only when every pool in an arena is empty the reserved memory for the arena is returned to the C-memory management, this is described [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9485a0dbddcee014821b41c960133632bb68b33c/Objects/obmalloc.c#L2080-L2097):

> ```
> /* All the rest is arena management.  We just freed
>  * a pool, and there are 4 cases for arena mgmt:
>  * 1. If all the pools are free, return the arena to
>  *    the system free().  Except if this is the last
>  *    arena in the list, keep it to avoid thrashing:
>  *    keeping one wholly free arena in the list avoids
>  *    pathological cases where a simple loop would
>  *    otherwise provoke needing to allocate and free an
>  *    arena on every iteration.  See bpo-37257.
>  * 2. If this is the only free pool in the arena,
>  *    add the arena back to the `usable_arenas` list.
>  * 3. If the "next" arena has a smaller count of free
>  *    pools, we have to "slide this arena right" to
>  *    restore that usable_arenas is sorted in order of
>  *    nfreepools.
>  * 4. Else there's nothing more to do.
>  */
> ```

Returning an arena to C-memory management doesn't enforce that the memory is returned to the OS, but in most cases 1MB is big enough that the C-memory manager will not "sit" on it, but return it immediately to OS.

---

In a nutshell: it is not easy to predict when memory is really returned to OS, as only chunks of 1MB can be returned by pymalloc, but this happens when the whole chunk is unused, which might be prevented by even one object which is alive and lives in this otherwise empty arena.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Reading the pymalloc allocator docs (that you linked to) I can only find a reference to "arenas" and not "area". I also notice the docs mention 256 KiB and not MB, just wanted to check if you perhaps made a typo. Thanks again for taking the time to write this down.

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt You are right, area was a typo. I have used 256MB from the memory but was wrong: for 64bit systems it is 1MB and 256KB for 32bits.